# Add a max value to input field with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a simple minus/plus jsfiddle to add or remove a number from an input field. However, I am trying to figure out the best way to set a max value meaning that if a user attempted to either type a number greater than 10 or used the plus feature that they cannot go past 10. What is the best way to achieve that?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
// This button will increment the value
$('.qtyplus').click(function(e){
    // Stop acting like a button
    e.preventDefault();
    // Get the field name
    fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
    // Get its current value
    var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
    // If is not undefined
    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
        // Increment
        $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 1);
    } else {
        // Otherwise put a 0 there
        $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
    }
});
// This button will decrement the value till 0
$(".qtyminus").click(function(e) {
    // Stop acting like a button
    e.preventDefault();
    // Get the field name
    fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
    // Get its current value
    var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name='+fieldName+']').val());
    // If it isn't undefined or its greater than 0
    if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
        // Decrement one
        $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal - 1);
    } else {
        // Otherwise put a 0 there
        $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
    }
});
```

});

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/laelitenetwork/puJ6G/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just interested in a JS/jQuery solution, simply change line 11:

```
 if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal < 10) {
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^---------[Add this to line 11
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/snwxaLx7/

To keep the value to 10 rather than to reset to 0, change line 16:

```
      $('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(10);
                                             ^^-----[Change 0 into 10
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/v1pje44v/

Comment: Is there a way to have it to where when it reaches 10 it just stays there? instead of resetting to 0. Also, they could still potentially enter in their own number I would want to ensure they couldn't

Comment: @Lynx See update. If a number greater than 10 is manually entered, the value will change to 10 on a `blur`, `key`,  `click`, or `focus`(on another element), etc..

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `plus` and `minus` buttons to achieve this. `input` type `number` with `min` and `max` attributes will do this for you.

```js
<input type='Number' name='quantity' value='0' class='qty' max="10" min="0" />
```

Refer [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/puJ6G/2568/) if you still want to go with *buttons* and prevent user going beyond **10**

Comment: This would be a neat solution. However, browser support is lacking it seems. I need this to be used on older browsers as well.