# jQuery max value input field on condition of other field

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are two fields, if the first field `discountType` and `discountAmount`. What I would like to achieve is this: if `discountType` equals `percentage` the input `discountAmount` only accepts a number between 0 and 100. If `discountType` equals `absolute` any number should be accepted in `discountAmount`.

I have read two similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316709/how-to-set-the-max-value-and-min-value-of-input-in-html5-by-javascript-or-jque) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758057/add-a-max-value-to-input-field-with-jquery) and tried with the `prop()` and the `attr()` methods, but without success.

My code currently looks like this (with the `.prop()`):

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="form-control-label required" for="coupon_discountType">Discount type
      </label>
      <select id="coupon_discountType" name="coupon[discountType]" class="form-control">
         <option value="percentage">percentage</option>
         <option value="absolute">absolute</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div>
      <label for="coupon_discountAmount" class="form-control-label required">Amount
      </label>
      <div class="input-group">
         <div class="input-group-prepend" id="absolute">
            <span class="input-group-text">€</span>
         </div>
         <input type="text" id="coupon_discountAmount" name="coupon[discountAmount]" required="required" class="form-control" />
         <div class="input-group-append" id="percentage">
            <span class="input-group-text">%</span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#coupon_discountType").change(function() {
    if($(this).val() === 'percentage') {
        $("#coupon_discountAmount").prop('max', 100);
        $('#absolute').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('#absolute').show();
    }
    if($(this).val() === 'absolute') {
        $('#percentage').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('#percentage').show();
    }
}).change();
```

Or a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hjg27zmv/1/)

Comment: Why not use two separate inputs which you could also hide/show along with the symbol.  Then you could set up rules for each discount type on each field.

Comment: @James, I could do that, but that would require me to change a whole lot of other code as well and I like the idea of having as few fields as possible (and a smaller DB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the below JSFIDDLE:

01) [Fiddle with input type as number](http://jsfiddle.net/hjg27zmv/2/)
02) [Fiddle with input type as text](http://jsfiddle.net/hjg27zmv/3/)

**JS Code**:

In below code, have checked whether "coupon_discountAmount" field have attribute "max" or "min". If they are present and value entered is not falling within specified range of "max" or "min", then just changing value in "coupon_discountAmount" to respective "max" or "min" values.

```
$("#coupon_discountAmount").change(function(event){
    // restricting to max value specified
    if( typeof $(this).attr('max') != 'undefined' ) {
        if( !isNaN($(this).val()) && (parseInt($(this).val()) > $(this).attr('max')) ) {
            $(this).val($(this).attr('max'));
        }
    }
    // restricting to min value specified
    if( typeof $(this).attr('min') != 'undefined' ) {
        if( !isNaN($(this).val()) && (parseInt($(this).val()) < $(this).attr('min')) ) {
            $(this).val($(this).attr('min'));
        }
    }
});
```

Hope I am getting right here, this is what you were looking in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I will prefer *input* event instead of *change*. You can create a function to check the *value* of the element. If the value does not fall in the range, you can remove the last character from the *value*.

**Working code Example**:

```js
$('body').on('input', '#coupon_discountType, #coupon_discountAmount',function(e) {
  if(e.target.id == 'coupon_discountType')
    $('#coupon_discountAmount').val('');
  if($('#coupon_discountType').val() === 'percentage') {
    $('#absolute').hide();
    checkValue();
  }
  else {
    $('#absolute').show();
  }
  if($(this).val() === 'absolute') {
    $('#percentage').hide();
  }
  else {
    $('#percentage').show();
  }
});
$('#coupon_discountType').trigger('input');

function checkValue(){
  var re = /^\d+$/;
  var s = $('#coupon_discountAmount').val();
  if (!(re.test(s) && s >= 0 && s <= 100)) { //check if not number and not in the range of 0-100
    if(s.trim() != '') //check if any value present
      $('#coupon_discountAmount').val(s.slice(0, -1)); //reset the value by removing the last character
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="form-control-label required" for="coupon_discountType">Discount type
      </label>
      <select id="coupon_discountType" name="coupon[discountType]" class="form-control">
         <option value="percentage">percentage</option>
         <option value="absolute">absolute</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div>
      <label for="coupon_discountAmount" class="form-control-label required">Amount
      </label>
      <div class="input-group">
         <div class="input-group-prepend" id="absolute">
            <span class="input-group-text">€</span>
         </div>
         <input id="coupon_discountAmount" name="coupon[discountAmount]" required="required" class="form-control" />
         <div class="input-group-append" id="percentage">
            <span class="input-group-text">%</span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```